# Specifying Image Path File From Another Folder in WEB-INF?

Tags: java, jsp, path, include, jstl

I'm including a separate JSP page (`header.jsp`) into my current `home.jsp` page as goes:

`<jsp:include page='/WEB-INF/Header/header.jsp'/>`

In that `header.jsp` page, I have an image as follows:

`<img id="myImage" src="<c:url value='../Images/myImage.jpg'/>" />`

But my image is not displaying on my `home.jsp` even though all the other elements (i.e. paragraphs, anchor links, etc.) found inside `header.jsp` is displaying normally on the `home.jsp` page as it should.

My folder structure goes:

```
MyProject
   WebContent
      WEB-INF
         Header
            header.jsp
         Images
            myImage.jpg
         Views
            Home
               home.jsp
```

How do I specify the path file to my image (`<img id="myImage" src="<c:url value='?/myImage.jpg'/>" />`) from within my `header.jsp` file?

Comment: Try `<c:url value='/WEB-INF/Images/myImage.jpg'/>`?

Comment: I have tried it before posting this question.  It didn't work

Comment: `WEB-INF` is protected, probably `c:url` cannot access it which means web server does not have access to it directly. If you really want to do so, you might need to implement your own method which can load image blob into page. From that, you can use absolute physical path to retrieve your image from anywhere.

Comment: Even if I move my `Images` folder out of `WEB-INF` (but still within `WebContent` folder) and adjust the path file to `/Images/myImage.jpg` it's still not showing the picture.

Comment: `/Images/myImage.jpg` only works if it's coded directly in the `home.jsp`.  But I can't do that as my image is part of other `<div>` structures in my `header.jsp`.

Comment: Was the url populated correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have it working:

`img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Images/myImage.jpg"`

Please let me know if this is an ideal way to go about this in JSP.